# AngularJS form and null/empty values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am working with a somewhat dynamic AngularJS form. In other words, I am able to add rows of input fields, etc. So my approach was to start with a `$scope.formData` empty object, to encapsulate all the properties that are bound to both static and dynamic HTML form elements.

The AngularJS code is as follows:

```
(function() {
    var formApp = angular.module("formApp", []);
    formApp.controller("FormCtrl", function ($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.formData.subscribers = [
            { name: null, email: null }
        ];
        $scope.addSubscriber = function() {
            $scope.formData.subscribers.push({ name: null, email: null });
        };
    });
})();
```

The HTML for the AngularJS form:

```
<body data-ng-app="formApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="FormCtrl">
        <p>
            Name of Topic: <input type="text" data-ng-model="formData.title" placeholder="enter a title" />
        </p>
        Subscribers:
        <button data-ng-click="addSubscriber()">Add subscriber</button>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="subscriber in formData.subscribers">
                <td><input type="text" data-ng-model="subscriber.name" placeholder="enter name" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" data-ng-model="subscriber.email" placeholder="enter email" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr style="margin:1em 0;" />
        <p>
            <em>Debug info</em>: {{ formData }}
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note the *Debug info* section at the end, which displays the `$scope.formData` object and its contents. I have a couple of issues with the way I have implemented this form.

- When the page first loads, there is no `formData.title` property in the `$scope`, but since it is bound to the Title input text field, when I start typing a value, the `title` property gets added to the `$scope`. However when I delete the value in the input text field, the `formData.title` property still exists in the `$scope` as an empty string. I suppose this is okay, but I really want to clean up empty or null values when submitting the form. I would like to do it on the client side if it is easy to do so, so the server side code does not have to clean up anything.
- With the dynamic *Subscribers* section, I can keep adding as many rows as I want, but ultimately, I would like to filter out all empty *subscriber* objects on the client side.

Does AngularJS have any options for detecting and cleaning null/empty values in the `$scope` before further processing, such as a `$http` POST?

**Note** I have set up a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webuser7/1ua6oj5e/) for this example.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) $parsers and overwrite the default HTML input element.

With this implementation you can have control over the model value all the time. 
So in your case you can set the model to null whenever the view value is empty String.

```
var inputDefinition = function () {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  require: '?ngModel',
  link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
    if (ngModel) {
      var convertToModel = function (value) {
        return value === '' ? null : value;
      };
      ngModel.$parsers.push(convertToModel);
    }
  }
};
/**
* Overwrite default input element.
*/
formApp.directive('input', inputDefinition);
```

Here is the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9sjra07q/

Comment: this interesting directive seems to convert properties with empty values to null instead of removing/filtering out null and empty values.

Answer (score 2):

I try and avoid using watchers for performance reasons. With that being said, this really isn't as much of an Angular question as it is a JavaScript question. Since you have total control over when the data is passed off to the service I would simply clean it up first. This is fairly simple since your data structure is so shallow.

https://jsfiddle.net/1ua6oj5e/9/

```
(function() {
    var formApp = angular.module("formApp", []);
    formApp.controller("FormCtrl", function ($scope, $timeout) {

        // Remove junkiness
        var _remove = function remove(item) {
            if ($scope.formData.title === undefined || $scope.formData.title === '') {
                delete $scope.formData.title;
            }
        };


        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.formData.subscribers = [
            { name: null, email: null }
        ];
        $scope.addSubscriber = function() {
            $scope.formData.subscribers.push({ name: null, email: null });
        };

        // Submit to test functionality
        $scope.submit = function() {

            // Remove title if empty
            _remove($scope.formData.title);

            /* Remove name and email if empty.
             * If your list of fields starts to get large you could always
             * just nest another iterator to clean things up.                 
             */

            angular.forEach($scope.formData.subscribers, function(sub) {
                _remove(sub.name);
                _remove(sub.email);
            });

        };
    });
})();
```

Comment: you are absolutely right, it is a JavaScript question, in an AngularJS context. The data structure is simplified to focus on the issue at hand, but it is shallow. In an ideal world, I would like to delete all non-object properties that are null or empty, and all object properties whose own properties are empty or null. I sense the need for some recursion to fulfill the requirement.

Comment: Totally, for any hierarchical data structure recursion is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

```
function replacer(key, value) {
    if (value == "" || value == null) {
       return undefined;
    }
  return value;
}

var foo = {foundation: "", model: {year: 2015, price:null}, week: 45, transport: "car", month: 7};
foo = JSON.stringify(foo, replacer);
foo =JSON.parse(foo);
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: this is pretty neat. Only downside is that in the case of `model: {year:null, price:null}`, the final outcome would include an empty object for `model:{}` instead of completely removing `model` from `foo`. But I will keep this approach in mind for other scenarios. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Added Watcher on formData,

```
$scope.$watch('formData',function(n,o){
      if(typeof $scope.formData.title !== 'undefined' && $scope.formData.title === "" ){
        delete $scope.formData.title;
      }
},true);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1ua6oj5e/6/

For all the dynamic fields you should use angular form validation, you should see this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: given the number of static and dynamic fields in my actual form, I am concerned about how large this `$watch` function implementation would become. And performance may be an issue. I responded to an other answer (from @Swordfish0321) that this is, at its core, a JS question rather than an AngularJS one. If I could traverse the `$scope` object and remove all non-object properties that are either empty or null, and all object properties whose own properties are all empty or null, that will address my requirement.