# Have Rails save valid attributes even if other attributes are invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that autosaves. I would like to be able to run validations and return error messages to the user, but I would also like to save all of the valid attributes. The frontend is angular so it would be a little annoying if you expected everything that is valid to save.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
# @user = <User name: "Chill Dude" favorite_color: "blue">
@user.save(name: '', favorite_color: "red")
@user.errors #=> ["Name cannot be null"]
@user.reload #=> <User name: "Chill Dude" favorite_color: "red">
```

I'm sure I could come up with some big complicated solution tapping in to `object.errors`, but I was wondering if there was any simple, rails-y way to do this?

Comment: yr saving `@user` then calling `@object.reload`, actually it should not save it if having validation on it.

Comment: Obviously that is default behavior. I'm asking if there is a way to save the valid attributes?

Comment: you saved user but, object has the prevoius data and errors of, so them can't belong to the updated user. Validate after :`@user.errors`

Comment: that is strange behavoiur, please add yuor model to post

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ there is a complete code example

Comment: @OneChillDude, Try all over again, it should not actually.

Comment: @7urkm3n I realize that Rails *doesn't* save the record if there are invalid attributes. That wasn't the question. The question was how can I make rails save the attributes that *are valid* while rejecting the ones that are not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage the `errors` object and **reset only the columns with errors back to their previous values**:

```
u = User.first
u.name = nil               # invalid value
u.favorite_color = "red"   # ok value

# run validations and set the errors object
u.valid? 
# => false

# this shows the attributes with errors
u.errors.keys 
# => [:name]

# restore the attributes with errors
u.restore_attributes(u.errors.keys)

# other attributes should stay changed:
u.favorite_color
# => "red"

# save should succeed now
u.save
# => true
```

See [`Errors`](http://g%20api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html) and [`restore_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-restore_attributes) docs.

Update: Ah, I just noticed you wrote about *big complicated solution using errors* in the question, well, I think this is rails-y enough:

```
# any model or ApplicationRecord in Rails 5
def save_valid_attributes
  restore_attributes(errors.keys) unless valid?
  save   # or perhaps even save(validate: false) to speed things up, 
         # if validations are independent of each other
end
```

Comment: Bravo, two claps for reading the question and posting an awesome response

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: I wouldn't call this "rails-y", but it should work. I would prefer to not send empty values from the UI. In this situation, rails (really ActiveRecord), is doing it's job in rejecting an invalid model.

I highly recommend reviewing handling this in the UI. I found a post that looks to be useful here: [AngularJS form and null/empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725499/angularjs-form-and-null-empty-values)

That said, this may be a bit of a wild idea, but this is what I would do if I could not solve the issue UI-side. This will take the posted parameters, and reject those that are blank before updating the model. The same logic could be leveraged for a save option. This would probably be a good candidate for a helper, to remove the extra logic from the controller.

```
def update
  clean_params = my_params.reject {|a| my_params[a].blank? }
  if @model.update(clean_params)
    # ...good
  else
    # ...bad
  end
end


private

def my_params
  params.require(:model).permit(:attr1, :attr2)
end
```

See more info on reject here: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject

Comment: I think you are missing the core concept here. The point is not to handle null values, the point is to handle any invalid attribute